# Ionic Sygic Embedded Integration

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, sygic

Has anyone successfully integrated the Sygic embedded app with Ionic using Capacitor?

I attempted it with the capacitor plugin but encountered difficulties.

I would appreciate any insights or tips on how to resolve this issue.